# How does TCL compare the lists?

Tags: tcl

I have the lists below:

```
list1 = "a b c"
list2 = "a b c d e f"
```

I am using the commands below to check if any element of list2 is present in list1. How does TCL compare the two lists? What is the value of the index used for the foreach loop below? Is it 3 (list1) or 6 (list2)?

```
    foreach list_1 $list1 list_2 $list2  {
        if {$list1 == $list2} {
             set FAIL 1
             break
           } else {
             set FAIL 0
                 break
           }
            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code can be simplified to `set FAIL [expr {$list1 == $list2}]` but it doesn't do what you say you want...

Comment: Using [`struct::set`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/struct/struct_set.md) from tcllib is the way I'd go

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to set FAIL if any element of list2 is present in list1, so you could do:

```
set FAIL 0
foreach list_2 $list2  {
    if {$list_2 in $list1} {
        set FAIL 1
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. The [`in` operator](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm) is underappreciated.

Comment: In some cases, it can be better to convert `list2` to (the keys of) a dictionary and use `dict exists`, as `in` is linear in the size of `list2`. Doing it that way has quite a bit of overhead, but can be asymptotically faster.

Answer (score 1):

When looping over multiple lists like you're doing, these will be the values of the loop variables for each iteration:

```
iteration  list_1  list_2
        1    a       a
        2    b       b
        3    c       c
        4    ""      d
        5    ""      e
        6    ""      f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 proc listComp {LIST1 LIST2} {
     set diff {}
     foreach i $LIST2 {

         if {[lsearch -exact $LIST1 $i]==-1} {
             lappend diff $i
         }
     }
     return $diff
 }


set LIST1 " a b c "
set LIST2 " a b c d e f "
puts " LIST1 = \{$LIST1\}\n LIST2 = \{$LIST2\}\n  The element \{[listComp $LIST1 $LIST2]\} of LIST2  does'nt exist in LIST1  "


            ## Heading ##Result
  LIST1 = { a b c }
  LIST2 = { a b c d e f }
  The element {d e f} of LIST2  does'nt exist in LIST1
```

Visit https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/listcomp+-Compare+the+Contents+of+two+Lists